# C++ Binary Search Tree using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

Hi can someone explain to me why the following isn't allowing me to use root.getLeft() as an argument to my recursion? From my understanding passing root.getLeft() as an argument to my binary search tree should work?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    Node(int value, Node* left, Node* right)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->left = left;
        this->right = right;
    }

    int getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    Node* getLeft() const
    {
        return left;
    }

    Node* getRight() const
    {
        return right;
    }

private:
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

class BinarySearchTree
{
public:
    static bool contains(const Node& root, int value)
    {
        if (root.getValue() != value){
            return true;
        }
        if (root.getLeft() != NULL){
            return BinarySearchTree::contains(root.getLeft(), value);
        }
        if (root.getRight() != NULL){
            return BinarySearchTree::contains(root.getRight(), value);
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

The problem message I am receiving is:
message: 'no suitable constructor exists to convert from "Node *" to "Node"'

Comment: How is it "not allowing you"?

Comment: Even with the change that you made (`Node& -> Node*`) your `contains` function still contains bugs. 1) You are returning true when `root.getValue() != value` when you should return true only if they are equal. 2) Your function never checks the right subtree because you `return` when you check the left subtree. If you want to check them both then you should have `return contains(root.getLeft(), value) || contains(root.getRight(), value)`....

Comment: And lastly, your function doesn't take advantage of the fact that your tree is a binary search tree. Your function intends to check at most every node to find the target, when it would be better to make a decision on whether to go left or right based on `value` and how it compares to `root.getValue()`. Remember that in a BST, every node in a root's left subtree is less than the root, and every node in its right subtree is greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `contains` takes a `Node&` and you are giving it a `Node*`.
You can fix that by deferencing the pointer you get from `getLeft` and `getRight`.

```
static bool contains(const Node& root, int value)
{
    if (root.getValue() != value){
        return true;
    }
    if (root.getLeft() != NULL){
        return BinarySearchTree::contains(*root.getLeft(), value);
    }
    if (root.getRight() != NULL){
        return BinarySearchTree::contains(*root.getRight(), value);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because

```
bool BinarySearchTree::contains(const Node& root, int value);
```

takes a `const Node&` but

```
Node* Node::getLeft() const;
```

provides a `Node*`.